# make exec function inside forEach do one by one

Tags: node.js

I'm getting stuck in problem with asynchronous of nodejs.
I want to resize on images in folder, `resize` is an executable binary file.
The problem is my  `resize` cannot be executed multiple times at same time. so that I use Array.prototype.forEach instead of async.forEach to expect that each file will be processed one by one.

```
var exec  = require('child_process').exec;

exec('ls ' + IMAGE_FOLDER, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {throw error;}
    var fileList = stdout.split("\n");
    fileList.pop();  //Remove the last element that null
    fileList.forEach(function(imageFile, index, array) {
        var inFile = IMAGE_FOLDER + imageFile;
        console.log(inFile);
        exec('resize ' +  inFile, function(err, stdout, stderr){
            if (err) {
                console.log(stderr);
                throw err;
            }
            console.log('resized ' + imageFile );
        })
    });
});
```

But the result I got is the behavior of my code is none-block, it prints out:

```
image1 
image2
...
resized image1
resized image2
...
```

I expected the behavior of printout should be:

```
image1
resize image1
image2
resize image2
...
```

Please show me where I was wrong. Any help is vary appreciate.

Comment: do you find the solution? if yes, please post your answer

Comment: I did alternative solution, but I think you can try with below suggestion from Jyotman Singh. Leave a comment if it works.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.forEach` will execute you javascript code synchronously without waiting for the asynchronous functions to finish thus will end each loop before waiting for the callbacks to trigger.

Assuming you know about the `async` library, you should use `async.series()` method. It will do exactly what you want. Read about it [here](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series).

Comment: But how can I loop over all file in folder. async.series() is required an array or object of functions.

Comment: Create an array similar to the way you are using `forEach` above. Inside forEach just a push a new function to an empty array in the format that `async.series` requires. After that just feed that array to `async.series`.

Comment: I'll try with you suggestion. Thanks so much!